# Trouble with subquery results

Tags: mysql

Struggling to find how I can show in the results from my query the max registrationpaid amount. As it stands I can only output the name. It's for an assignment and it has to be a subquery. Thanks for any help

```
 SELECT FirstName, LastName
   FROM tblattendees
   WHERE (SELECT MAX(RegistrationPaid) FROM tblregistration
   WHERE tblattendees.AttendeeID = tblregistration.AttendeeID) 
   >= ALL (SELECT  MAX(RegistrationPaid) FROM tblregistration GROUP BY AttendeeID);
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If understand your query correctly you want a list of attendies whose max registration paid is equal to the max regitration paid for any attendee.

If so it can be done by joining a couple of sub queries:-

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, sub0.MaxRegistrationPaid
FROM tblattendees
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT AttendeeID, MAX(RegistrationPaid) AS MaxRegistrationPaid
    FROM tblregistration
    GROUP BY AttendeeID
) sub0
ON tblattendees.AttendeeID = sub0.AttendeeID
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(RegistrationPaid) AS MaxRegistrationPaid
    FROM tblregistration
) sub1
ON sub0.MaxRegistrationPaid = sub1.MaxRegistrationPaid
```

Could also be done using HAVING:-

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, MAX(RegistrationPaid) AS MaxRegistrationPaid
FROM tblattendees
INNER JOIN tblregistration
ON tblattendees.AttendeeID = tblregistration.AttendeeID
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(RegistrationPaid) AS HighestRegistrationPaid
    FROM tblregistration
) sub1
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
HAVING MaxRegistrationPaid >= HighestRegistrationPaid
```